# How to plot two columns (String + double) using Pandas or numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataFrame and I want to plot two columns. All the examples i saw **used only numbers as their values** but when I try to plot a columns that has strings then I get an error. How can I plot a string columns?

```
d = {'one' : np.random.rand(10),
     'two' : np.random.rand(10)}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.plot(style=['o','rx'])
plt.show()
```

DataFrame sample (I want to plot AvgTemp and StateName)

```
STATION;"STATION_NAME";"LATITUDE";"LONGITUDE";"LATLONG";"AvgTemp";"MaxTemp";"MinTemp";"StateName";"Zip";"State";"Date"

GHCND:USW00094746;"WORCESTER MA US";42.2706;-71...   -71.8731";55.0;58.0;47.0;"Massachusetts";1602...
```

Comment: What *kind* of plot are you looking for? The plot you showed as an example is a scatter plot, but this doesn't make much sense as far as categorical data

Comment: I want to show what is the average temperature for each state using a plot. But that is all what I could do. Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, Here's a minimal example of what you want to do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'state': ['a','b','a','c','b','c'], 'value':[23,43,12,87,33,11]})
df.groupby('state')['value'].mean().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]